# From two dates and frequency get daterange list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have two dates:

'1990-01-01'

'2020-02-18'

I would want to convert them in a date range list of as maximum, 25 years:

```
[ ['1990-01-01', '2015-01-01'], ['2015-01-01', '2020-02-18'] ]
```

Or as maximun, 5 years:

```
[ ['1990-01-01', 1995-01-01'], [1995-01-01', '2000-01-01'], ['2000-01-01', '2005-01-01'], ['2005-01-01', '2010-01-01'], ['2010-01-01', '2015-01-01'], ['2015-01-01', '2020-01-01'], ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-18'] ]
```

I tried with pandas.interval_range with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `pd.date_range`.

**Ex:**

```
data = pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '2020-02-18',freq="5YS")
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['1990-01-01', '1995-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2005-01-01',
               '2010-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2020-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5AS-JAN')
```

Comment: OP seems to want intervals though

Comment: Maybe just adding `list(zip(dti[:-1], dti[1:]))` should do it

Comment: That is what I tried. But i am not getting the final interval ( ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-18'] )

Comment: @Alfonso_MA. Add an additional check and append `end`: ex: `if '2020-02-18' not in data:
    data = data.append(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-18']))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [dateutil.rrule](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57) fits your needs. You can define a rule to generate all the datetimes you need, for example:

```
dstart=datetime.datetime(2001,1,1)
for a in rrule(YEARLY, dtstart=dstart, interval=5, count=5):
    print(a)
```

Grouping datetimes in pairs is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.date_range`. Since the spacing between the generated dates must be of 5 years, you'll have to add the end date yourself, then create the intervals from the generated dates:

```
start = '1990-01-01'
end = '2020-02-18'

s = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5YS').append(pd.DatetimeIndex([end]))

print(s)
DatetimeIndex(['1990-01-01', '1995-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2005-01-01',
               '2010-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-18'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Then use `zip` to create the interval:

```
list(zip(s[:-1], s[1:]))

[(Timestamp('1990-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('1995-01-01 00:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('1995-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')),
 (Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-02-18 00:00:00'))]
```